# Launching Eclipse always Launches the Installer

Tags: 16.04, eclipse, workspaces

Recently I have installed Eclipse.Neon on my Ubuntu 16.04.
I have created a desktop shortcut for launching Eclipse from my Desktop.

Here's what happens when I click on the icon.

[image: Launching Eclipse from Desktop]

Everytime it opens with which Version I want to use, I choose Eclipse IDE for Javascript and Web Developers and then I choose the same installation folder I had created earlier and then click Install.

Is there a better way to launch the installation folder I had created earlier?

Here's my desktop shortcut

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse
Exec=/home/shiv/Softwares/Eclipse/eclipse-installer/eclipse-inst
Icon=/home/shiv/Softwares/Eclipse/eclipse-installer/icon.xpm
Type=Application
```

~

Answer (score 1):

Okay.. I found a solution!!

This is what I did. I created a new desktop shortcut with the following content.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse
Exec=/home/shiv/eclipse/javascript-neon/eclipse/eclipse
Icon=/home/shiv/eclipse/javascript-neon/eclipse/icon.xpm
Type=Application
```

Basically, I updated the contents of Exec and Icon with these pointing to the already installed Javascript-Neon.

Thanks